# Swift 2.1 - How to pass index row of collection view cell to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to send indexPath.row of selected cell in collection view to a destination controller (detail view) and I've done the following so far

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let recipeCell: Recipe!

    recipeCell = recipe[indexPath.row]

    var index: Int = indexPath.row

    performSegueWithIdentifier("RecipeDetailVC", sender: recipeCell)
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "RecipeDetailVC" {

        let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as? RecipeDetailVC

        if let recipeCell = sender as? Recipe {
            detailVC!.recipe = recipeCell
            detailVC!.index = index
        }
    }
}
```

indexPath.row is a type of NSIndexPath so I've tried to convert to Int but I get `Cannot assign value of type '(UnsafePointer<Int8>,Int32) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>' to type 'Int'` at runtime

In the destination view controller I've initialized `var index = 0`
to receive the indexPath.row value

Any idea why I get this error at runtime?

Comment: Where are you getting this error? In which line? In the `prepareForSegue` where are you getting the `index` from? It seems like a property variable but in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` its a local variable. Did you mean to set the index property to indexPath.row in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the following out of the function and make it a property.

```
var index: Int = indexPath.row
```

In prepareForSegue you have the following:

```
detailVC!.index = index
```

The variable 'index' isn't declared in the class or locally, so what you get is a function named 'index' which is defined as:

```
func index(_: UnsafePointer<Int8>, _: Int32) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>
```

If you make 'index' a property, it will be used instead of the function of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

It's a collectionView so I believe you should be using indexpath.item not .row

Comment: collectionView itself works ok with row but indexpath.item by default is a type of Int so it should be a better choice for me. My problem was with `var index` which I should have made it at global scope. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following line in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`:

```
var index: Int = indexPath.row
```

This declares `index` as being local to this function only. Then in `prepareForSegue` you have:

```
detailVC!.index = index
```

Since you're not getting a compilation error, `index` must also be defined somewhere else. It's this somewhere else variable that `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` should be setting. It is probably just

```
index = indexPath.row
```

Comment: You're right. I didn't have a global variable index and I was trying to access this local index that is only scoped for `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` inside `prepareForSegue`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "RecipeDetailVC" {

        let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as? RecipeDetailVC

        if let recipeCell = sender as? Recipe {
            detailVC!.recipe = recipeCell
            detailVC!.index = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()?.first?.item
        }
    }
}
```